# If redis timesout during a SET operation, could data in the redis db have been modified anyway?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, timeout, redis

I'm using redis for analytics in a ruby on rails application hosted on heroku and I'm thinking about how I should handle redis timeouts. Redis timeouts don't happen too frequently, but they do happen. Here's where I would handle them:

```
begin
  Timeout::timeout(5) {
    # an operation that modifies data in redis db
  }
rescue Timeout::Error
  # do something
end
```

I'm wondering: if redis timesout and execution is thrown to the rescue block, is it possible that data in the redis db have been modified during this? Is there any guarantee that it hasn't been modified (in which case I might create a background job to retry this operation later)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Redis got the command, I would not expect it to rollback if the client is unable to receive the ACK, and if I understand the source code correctly it won't. If you don't want redis to execute in the case of a timeout you need to use a transaction.